# Open IndexedDb transaction on IE11 throw NotFoundError

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, indexeddb, web-worker

I try to open and save some data in an indexedDB.

The indexeddb is encapsulate in a webworker but each time i try to open a transaction on IE11, it throws a "notFoundError" (works well on FF).

This is my simplified code :

```
var dbApi = indexedDB || webkitIndexedDB || mozIndexedDB || msIndexedDB;
var transactionApi = IDBTransaction || webkitIDBTransaction || mozIDBTransaction || msIDBTransaction || {};

var request = dbApi.open('myDB', 1);
var db;

request.onerror = handle_error;
request.onupgradeneeded = handle_upgrade;

request.onsuccess = function(event) {
    console.log("Open db ok");
    db = event.target.result;
    try {
        var t = db.transaction(["packet"], (transactionApi.READ_WRITE ? transactionApi.READ_WRITE : 'readwrite')); // Throw error here
        t.onsuccess = function() {
            var os = t.objectStore("packet");
            var cmd = os.put("Some data", -2);
        }
    }
    catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I answer myself : on IE11, we can't create indexeddb from webworker. Db has to be created from main thread and web worker is able to access it after.

Comment: Could you add an example?